# Why didn't Opera release Opera Browser version 13 and 14?

Tags: opera

I'm really curious why Opera didn't release version 13 and 14, they skipped directly to version 15. Could you tell me why did they skip?.

Comment: Ask Opera, maybe?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Opera_web_browser#Version_15): "The version identifier 13 was skipped, thought to be for reasons of superstition, while 14 was used to refer to a WebKit-based release of Opera for Android."

Comment: @Indrek can you post this as an answer not an comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Wikipedia article on Opera version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_Opera_web_browser#Version_15):

> The version identifier 13 was skipped, thought to be for reasons of [superstition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triskaidekaphobia), while 14 was used to refer to a [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit)-based release of Opera for Android.

13 is considered an unlucky number in a lot of cultures. Microsoft Office is another example of software skipping version 13 (Office 2007 was version 12 and Office 2010 was version 14).

Comment: Triskaidekaphobia - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triskaidekaphobia

Comment: @Keltari Already linked to in the Wikipedia quote ;)